# Why will my basement room be one temperature all day but then will be different overnight?

Tags: basement, bedroom, temperature

My bedroom is in the basement of the house, as that is where the master is. All day the temperature will be 66-67 degrees. When my husband and I go to bed at night, it will increase to 70-71 throughout the night. Why? We do nothing different to the space or the basement in terms of closing doors, closing/opening vents, etc. We simply go to bed.

Comment: Do you run the AC and are there any ducts in the basement?

Comment: You are adding the heat of 2 human bodies.  If there is no air exchange, you will be heating the room.

Comment: For average humans, 120W for him, 97W for her. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116965

Comment: `We do nothing different to the space` ... yes, you do ... you occupy the space

Answer (score 4):

You're not taking into effect the heat generated by the human body. Normal surface temperature of a body runs about 95 degrees and there are two of you and breathing for two adults adds about 3.5 to 4 CFM of around 88 degrees air. Sleeping for eight hours will add quite a bit of heat to your basement.

Comment: It's really noticeable here in the winter. My house is unheated overnight and when I get up (normally having been woken by the heating coming on) the bedroom, despite its outside walls, is quite a bit warmer than the landing.

Answer (score 2):

It's body heat alright. Heat from a body that radiates about 90 watts (300 BTU) **per square foot**.  Oh, not your body... a different body that only visits during the day, but doesn't visit that room.

### The sun.  It's solar gain.

During the day, the sun's radiation is 300 BTU per square foot, warming the structure of the building which then seeps through the insulation.  This punishes top floor and sunny-side rooms much more than shady or basement rooms.

Unfortunately, your thermostat is in one of those rooms getting blasted by solar gain ( or more influenced by it than the basement), so it's calling for HVAC quite a lot during the day.

Once solar gain is done soaking through your building's structure and insulation, the balance changes and now the thermostat runs A/C less often, and the basement is no longer over-cooled.

Your ducting is not balanced. It's impossible for it to be balanced for both heat (solar gain helps) and cool (solar gain hurts).  So during summer it is over-cooling the basement in response to solar gain the basement is not experiencing.  That's why it's cool in there during the day.

The #1 thing you can do is run a "fan schedule" or simply run the fan at all times, to even out temperature among all rooms.